# Azure ADX ingest data across databases on the same cluster

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to find a way to ingest data from one database to another (same cluster), based on when the source table gets updated. We have an update query that is able to see across databases , however when I try to update the update policy with:

```
.alter table DataBase2.ChildTable policy update
'''
[
    {
        "IsEnabled": true,
        "Source": "DataBase1.SourceTable",
        "Query": "QueryFunction()"
    }
]
'''
```

This produces the following error:

```
 Error during execution of a policy operation: Source table does not exist for policy: 'IsEnabled = 'True', Source = 'DataBase1.SourceTable', Query = 'QueryFunction()', IsTransactional = 'False', PropagateIngestionProperties = 'False''
```

Anyone got any ideas?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found a solution:

Create a source table that is ingestion with a 0 time retention policy
The command:

```
.alter table SourceTableName policy retention 
'''
{
  "SoftDeletePeriod": "0", "Recoverability":"Disabled"
}
'''
```

This will make the table never commit any rows.

Next, for each of your update policies, you need to structure them as follows:

```
.alter table Childtable policy update @'[{"Source": "SourceTableName", "Query": "UpdateQuery()", "IsEnabled": "True", "IsTransactional": "True"}]'
```

This will make the child tables pull the rows as and when they are ingested, but the rows will NEVER be committed to the source table. Think of it as a stepping stone. I recommend having another DB that also ingests from the same source as a backup, allowing you to do .appends as needed (if ingestion ever fails) From here, you can add RLS to the child tables as wanted!

[Retention reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy)

[RLS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy)

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing**, and as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) explicitly mentions - it's not possible to have cross-database queries as part of an update policy.

One thing you could do is periodically run `.set-or-append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) commands to do cross-database ingestion, while leveraging the [database cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor) to guarantee that data gets processed exactly once.

[ ** Cross-database update policies may be supported in the future ]

Comment: Damn that's a shame. Is there a way we can restrict who can see a source table, while letting it populate child tables who non - restricted people can see? This will be on the same DB

Comment: see: [RLS policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy) and/or [restricted view access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy)

Comment: I have been reading over it, however when looking at ```Limitations
There's no limit on the number of tables on which Row Level Security policy can be configured.

The RLS policy can't be enabled on a table:

for which continuous data export is configured.
referenced by a query of an update policy.
on which restricted view access policy is configured.``` It appears we cannot set the source to restricted. In addition, when we did the child tables no longer were able to be updated